# Can I halt ongoing operations without terminating my R session?

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I sent API requests to get the address from a list of approximately 80,000 APIs.

I used the Google Maps API and the process finished, since the last request was 6 hours ago.

```
library(ggmap)
locations <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(data))
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  gc <- c(data[i, 2], data[i, 1]) 
  locations[i] <- revgeocode(as.numeric(gc))
}
```

It is still printing out the messages received from each API request and I'd like to use my R session to work on other problems. I can't terminate the session since the data only exists in my local environment and I haven't yet written it to a CSV or JSON file.

Here's what I've tried: I pressed stop a number of times.

Here's what I'd like to try: I could turn off my RStudio Server instance or I could turn off my EC2 instance that is hosting RStudio Server.

My concern is those will terminate the environment and cause me to lose the variables.

Do I have to just wait it out?

Comment: I think you'll need to ask RStudio support about this, but it's possible that if the messages aren't displayed (e.g. the window is minimized) they'll go faster.

Comment: I ended up waiting it out, but it's an interesting edge case

Comment: Is there some reason that you don't want to start a second R session, leaving the first running?

Comment: I wanted to use the data stored in the `locations` list.